# Float right table doesnt work

Tags: css

I tried to apply the float: right to the button and the text but its just not working because it destroys everything.

Any ideas?

```
                        <hr>
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="#" class="btn-primary left-cell"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Aktualisieren</a>
                            <span class="right-cell"> 14 neue Meldungen</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uoyh2fk9/

Comment: add `width: 100%;` to your `.table` .

Comment: tried already but then its broken again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what, "**destroys everything**" means, but it sounds like `flexbox` might work better for what you are trying to achieve. Remove the `display: table`'s from your divs and try the following:

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uoyh2fk9/4/)

If you would like to know more about `flexbox` and how it works, [here is a link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: thanks but my button is getting scretched then. also I want both things on the right side.

Comment: @Smythu Are you against using `flexbox`? Or do you have to use `display: table`?

Comment: well I just want to have both things next to each other and vertically aligned. so it seems the best option so far.

Comment: Flexbox is way better. Let me write up a solution real quick.

Comment: @Smythu, answer has been updated. Let me know if you have any questions or problems. :)

Comment: Woohoo! Glad to help! :) Flexbox is seriously the best, haha xD

Comment: I have another question. I might ask it here; how can I align a text on the left side now without losing the right align?

Comment: Did you try adding `text-align: left;` to your class?

Comment: Works for me. The text won't go left unless the containing div is larger than the width of the text. https://jsfiddle.net/uoyh2fk9/10/

Comment: I placed the text somewhere else. :p not in the table. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/uoyh2fk9/9/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border-red">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Aktualisieren</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 border-red">
      <span>14 neue Meldungen</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
      <hr class="horizontal-divider">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 border-red">
      <span>14 neue Meldungen</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border-red">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Aktualisieren</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added a responsive solution using the Bootstrap CDN to the example in JSFiddle.  If you want to use this jsfiddle make sure you also add the CDN external sources to the your solution.

You can change the column size to fit your solution.